# When does mysql_real_escape_string know which db server is in charge at the moment?

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql-real-escape-string

In a function call like this

```
$rs = getrs($dbh,"select firstname,lastname from users where userid='" . safe($uid) . "'")
```

would the safe function properly handle the sql injection?

the safe function basically does nothing but applying the mysql_real_escape_string over the passed argument which in this case is $uid.

If so, I don't see how.

I don't see how that would work cause the database handle `$dbh` and the function `safe()` are running in different contexts.

Is there a way to write a convenient function like the above one liner while making sure all the variables that are wrapped in a safe like function are properly escaped.

and also is there a function in PHP, that you pass the 4dbh and it tells you whether it's a mysql or mssql handle?

Comment: [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) accepts a second (optional) parameter -- the link identifier. You should explicitly pass an open connection's handle to this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When does mysql_real_escape_string know which db server is in charge
> at the moment?

From the [manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

> If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by
> mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to
> create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no
> connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is
> generated.

[...]

> would the safe function properly handle the sql injection?

In your particular case, yes it would.

> Is there a way to write a convenient function like the above one liner
> while making sure all the variables that are wrapped in a safe like
> function are properly escaped.

Some people like to use [sprintf](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for this. However, the correct way to do this now is using parameterized queries ([PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)).

> and also is there a function in PHP, that you pass the 4dbh and it
> tells you whether it's a mysql or mssql handle?

You could use [get_resource_type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-resource-type.php)

```
$dbh = mysql_connect();
echo get_resource_type($dbh); // mysql link
```

Comment: thank you so much for covering it all. I'd like to use PDO but I could not bring it down to a one-liner like the getrs function is. is there a pdo library that's got plenty of one or two-liners to do safe select,update and inserts?

Comment: @John your getrs function is not a true one-liner. How it differs from just a mysql_query call?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL to be properly escaped, use http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Juan, why is PDO better than mysql_real_escape_string? I ask this within the context of I never work with multi-byte chars and I always - always stick to UTF-8. Why should I change to PDO?

Comment: @JohnSmith If you end up using a different driver (not mysql) this will use the correct escaping mechanism for that driver.

Comment: OK. But If I don't plan on getting into "other drivers than mysql" and "other char sets than utf-8", am I not better off with mysql as opposed to PDO. As far as sql injection, they are identical and as far as the performance goes, I think mysql will beat PDO in executing certain statements cause PDO will case a roud trip in prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the silly question that can be answered just by reading the manual page, there is much more important problem stated:

> would the `safe` function properly handle the sql injection?

No.

As long as `safe()` function basically does nothing but applying the mysql_real_escape_string over the passed argument, it shouldn't be named this way. 
Because applying the mysql_real_escape_string has nothing to do with injections or safety at all.

At the very least **this function has to add quotes** around passed value in addition to escaping. It will make some queries erroneous but at least safe.

> Is there a way to write a convenient function like the above one liner while making sure all the variables that are wrapped in a safe like function are properly escaped.

Sure.
Use placeholders.

```
$rs = getrs($dbh,"select firstname,lastname from users where userid=?",$uid);
```

A custom handler will substitute the placeholder `?` with safely prepared value.

Here is a function I wrote long time ago with the same intention as your "oneliner" but more sensible one, with both safety and ease of use in mind.
It surely not ideal - no `%` chars have to be placed in the query directly as it's using printf syntax. And it does not have a placeholder for the identifiers (as well as many other handy placeholders). And of course an OOP implementation would be much more flexible, having neat distinct methods instead ugly "mode" variable.
But if you want a function

```
function dbget() {
  /*
  usage: dbget($mode, $query, $param1, $param2,...);
  $mode - "dimension" of result:
  0 - resource
  1 - scalar
  2 - row
  3 - array of rows
  */
  $args = func_get_args();
  if (count($args) < 2) {
    trigger_error("dbget: too few arguments");
    return false;
  }
  $mode  = array_shift($args);
  $query = array_shift($args);
  $query = str_replace("%s","'%s'",$query); 

  foreach ($args as $key => $val) {
    $args[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
  }

  $query = vsprintf($query, $args);
  if (!$query) return false;

  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$res) {
    trigger_error("dbget: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
    return false;
  }

  if ($mode === 0) return $res;

  if ($mode === 1) {
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) return $row[0];
    else return NULL;
  }

  $a = array();
  if ($mode === 2) {
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) return $row;
  }
  if ($mode === 3) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) $a[]=$row;
  }
  return $a;
}
?>
```

You may add your $dbh to it's call but I see no point in that.

> is there a function in PHP, that you pass the $dbh and it tells you whether it's a mysql or mssql handle

There is absolutely no point in having such function. 
When one have to use a database handler, they apparently have to know which database driver it belongs to.
Oh. And I hope you're no going to use mysql_real_escape_string with ms sql.

Comment: would the safe function properly handle the sql injection?
No.
As long as safe() function basically does nothing but applying the mysql_real_escape_string over the passed argument, it shouldn't be named this way. Because applying the mysql_real_escape_string has nothing to do with injections or safety at all.  -- Very Good!